# Zend Framework Response Filter to strip newlines and whitespaces between tags

Tags: php, zend-framework, filter

I am wondering if there exists any filter/plugin which does the following to a zend framework response:

1. Strip all unnecessary whitespaces from the HTML response
2. Strip all newlines between tags which are not used (e.g. between ul -> li elements: IE6 design errors)

Anyone know about something like that?

thanks

Comment: Zend_Filter_StringTrim
Zend_Filter_StripNewLines

Comment: hi arne. The first filter does only remove trailing whitespaces and the ones at the beginning. the second one does only strip \n and \r which is not complete. I would like to strip the whitespaces between the tags. thx

Answer (score 0):

you can solve that by telling the frontcontroller not to output but return the response.

```
$frontController->returnResponse(true);
$output = $frontController->dispatch();

// do with out output whatever you need

echo $output;
```

Comment: Hi zolex. thanks for the reply. I am actually looking for the part of "// do with output whatever you need"